# Последовательное выполнение Асинхронных операций (методов)

Tags: java, android

Неоднократно встречаюсь с одной и той же проблемой, когда у меня есть несколько асинхронных операций выполняемых в определённой последовательности, и в частности выполняемых четко последовательно, например: достаём значение из БД (realm), и после этого вызываем другую функцию, куда и передаём эти значения. Есть ли в java что-то на подобие "обещаний (promise)" или "будущее (future)"? Что бы не создавать новый поток, в котором будет крутится for с множеством if-ов. Если нет, то как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Есть такое. Попробуйте RxJava

Comment: Используйте колбеки. В колбеке предыдущей операции вызывать следующую. Называется callback hell =)

Comment: Есть такое, только в JavaScript, а вот Java в этом деле не преуспела, как я понял. Есть очень мощный фреймвёрк в виде RxJava 2, но при всех своих возможностях он такого не умеет, rx имеет множество инструментов, но по ним очень мало примеров. Один более менее похожий Scheduler.Worker, но как им воспользоваться?